# InvalidArgument topicName does not match projects/outrigger-170662/topics/gmail

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using Node.js and the googleapis package. Along with passport for authentication.

When I run this code on my Node.JS app:

```
 function start(user, oauth2){                                                                                                 
    // Start watching for new emails                                                                                            
    gmail.users.watch({                                                                                                         
    auth: oauth2,                                                                                                    
    userId: 'me',                                                                                                             
      resource: {                                                                                                               
        topicName: 'projects/outrigger-170662/topics/gmail',                                                                    
        labelIds: ["Inbox"]                                                                                                     
      }                                                                   `                                                      
    }, function(err){                                                                                                           
      if (err){                                                                                                                 
        console.log(err);                                                                                                       
      }                                                                                                                         
    });                                                                                                                            }
```

> **Note**: I am actually passing in the user object and oauth2client, so that is not the issue.

I get this error:

```
     data: { error: [Object] } },
  code: 400,
  errors:
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'invalidArgument',
       message: 'Invalid topicName does not match projects/outrigger-170622/topics/*' } ] }
```

I am using the following scopes:

```
  'email',
  'profile',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  'https://mail.google.com/',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts'
```

I have created the gmail topic on my google cloud console and set `allUsers` as a publisher. Is there something I am missing?

The site is live at https://outrigger.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, your actual project ID is `outrigger-170622`, however in your request you are sending `outrigger-170662`. It looks like this error is caused by a typo of 662 vs 622. Try fixing this and see if the error goes away.